# How to use Resources.Loadall for only .fbx, .obj files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, Resources.LoadAll(path) method would access T type in the specific path(e.g.Resources/Meshes/Buildings). Then we can add all these files to our array.

However, I can't specific any file like .fbx, .obj, .png, etc. The T type allows us to access only the Unity classes suck as GameObject, Texture2D, Mesh and so on...

Here is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;


public class AutoPre_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public Object[] tractorobj;
    public GameObject[] directoryAllFiles;
    public string[] Model_Folder;
    public List<GameObject> meshGameobj;

    private void Start()
    {
        loadModels();

    }

    public void loadModels()
    {
        meshGameobj = new List<GameObject>();
        directoryAllFiles = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Model/Equipment");

    }
}
```

The script compiled, smoothly. And when I ran the game, Resources.LoadAll would get every files in my folder(.fbx, .prefabs, .cs)

If I only need .fbx files, what should I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: wouldn't you rather need the prefabs of type `GameObject` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way you can distinguish .fbx and .prefabs just by typing the path because extensions are ignored. Here is what you can do:

1. Try placing your .fbx files into a new folder like: "Model/Equipment/FBXs".
2. Set the .fbx list through inspector.
3. Add a tag to .fbx files then after loadall filter the array, but I wouldn't recommend this method because wastes memory.